# How Can I set initial quantities on woocommerce product without changing the on product page cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the following php function to set initial product values on a woocommerce store's products for wholesale buyers.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {

   if( ! is_cart() && current_user_can( 'wholesale_buyer' ) )
       $args['input_value'] = 2; // Not on cart page

   return $args; 
}
```

The code is working for the most part.  The products on the product page are initially set to 2 and the products on the cart page are set to user selected values.

The issue is as follows:

The store has a products page with multiple products and a cart at the bottom of the page.
When the default values are set with this php function for the products on the products page, they are also set for the cart displayed at the bottom of the page.

How can I prevent my php function from targeting the initial quantities of the products in the cart at the bottom of the products page, while still changing the initial quantities of the products on the same page?

(I have read through all relevant questions on here that I could find.)